# Read rows in from database and assign the rows values to a string variable in Postgresql and C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have a table in my database consisting of one column which is NewLanguage(varchar).I insert new languages to the table and i want to select the rows of the table and assign them to a string variable splitted by ','.
I try to select the languages as in the code.

```
public string  SelectLanguagesFromDatabase()
    {

        NpgsqlCommand COM = new NpgsqlCommand(null,dbConnection);
        COM.CommandText = "select * from \"Languages\"";


    }
```

How can I select roes from database and assign them to string variable?

```
In an example
```

if Languages Column is

```
  NewLanguage

 C
 c++
 java
```

I want to have a a string as "C,c++,java".
How can I do that ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string_agg to concatenate all values from particular column in comma separated text like below:

```
SELECT string_agg (NewLanguage,',') FROM "Languages"
```

Comment: @Ilesh Patel I updated my method  then a i have another question which is what must be this method's return value?

Comment: if you store result into variable name like INTO var than it should be TEXT

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from the [user manual](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html) and using [Ilesh Patel's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24904630/21945) query:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Npgsql;

public static class NpgsqlUserManual
{
  public static void Main(String[] args)
  {
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=joe;Password=secret;Database=joedata;");
    conn.Open();

    NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT string_agg(NewLanguage,',') FROM Languages", conn);
    String results;

    try
    {
      results = (String)command.ExecuteScalar();
      Console.WriteLine("{0}", results);
    }


    finally
    {
      conn.Close();
    }
  }
}
```